# A partially obsolete word square?

Tags: crosswords, word-square

I'm slowly working on my next word square puzzle, and during the process, I crafted a partially obsolete order 5 square:

[image: Screenshot of a 5x5 grid where the center tile is the letter V.]

The clues, in no particular order are:

- A guarded hedge for deterring cattle.
- Roses are red, berries are black; woody and thorny, they might just attack.
- The first rising sun in the United States.
- Catalan feminine plural of mine.
- Reanimated, without the *e*.

<sub>***Note**: The words you're looking for are available in [YAWL](https://github.com/elasticdog/yawl), or if you prefer, my [5 letter word list created with YAWL](https://github.com/tacosontitan/brute-force-dictionary/blob/master/BruteForceDictionary/Text%20Files/FiveLetterWords.txt).*</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word square is:

> ```
>  ZOMBI
>  OXERS
>  MEVES
>  BRERE
>  ISSEI
> ```

This is because

> OXERS are guarded hedges for deterring cattle
>  BRERE is an ancient form of BRIAR(s) - woody and thorny, they might just attack!
>  ISSEI is a Japanese term for first-generation immigrants in North America
>  MEVES is the Catalan feminine(?) plural of "mine"
>  ZOMBI(e) r(e)animation is quit(e) th(e) probl(e)m

Comment: Ninjaed by about 30 seconds!